# Listview: duplicate values Items from ArrayList when scrolling bottom/up

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I am encountering a problem with my code.

I populate the Listview from ArrayList which in turn is populated by file-data.

The problem is when I scroll bottom or up I get duplicated items. How can I fix it?

Here is my code:

```
public class ListChannels extends ListActivity {

ArrayList<String> channelname = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_channels);


    listchannels();
    channelname = new ArrayList<String>(new LinkedHashSet<String>(channelname));
    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, R.layout.mylistchannel,
            R.id.Channelname,channelname));


}
```

The code where I populate the ArrayList from File

```
    InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(testFile.getReadStream());
            BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
            String key,value = null;
            do {
                key = buffreader.readLine();
                if(key != null)
                    value = buffreader.readLine();
                 channelname.add(key);


            } while (key != null && value != null);
```

I will appreciate your help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to log what you are reading from file to check if the problem is with that or the list.

Comment: but when do you populate the ArrayList from the File ?

Comment: The file is fine. In fact when i don't scroll the listview it reads all the lines accurately. But when i scroll to the bottom or up it keeps adding duplicate datas.

Comment: user, it's in the do while cycle. channelname.add(key);

Comment: You should read the entire contents of the file into the list when your app starts. Is that what you are doing? Why are you generating your arraylist from a LinkedHashSet? Your code where you are populating arraylist seems to be incomplete.

Comment: edit: I was reading somewhere that using LinkedHashSet removes the duplicate data but that didn't work for me.

Comment: Anyone can help me solve this issue?